# NullPointerException in java while trying to call a function of an object

Tags: java

```
public abstract class destination{

    //Here are the data that are common in each of the 'File Types'
    protected tree root;
    //constructor that will call the correct constructor when a derived children is made.
    public destination()
    {
        super();        //Will call the other constructors
    }
    public void get_info()
    {
    }
    public void print()
    {

    }
    public void add_comment(String comment)
    {
           root.add_comments(root, comment); //null pointer exception
    }

}
```

I'm coming from C++ so I've never had this issue before. Normally to access a function I could just go like root->add_comment(root, comment); and it would work just fine, but in java it's giving me a null pointer, do I have to initialize root? Because in the tree class I have an add_comment function which recursively adds a node into the tree.

Comment: Yes, you must initialize `root`. Even in C++ you cannot invoke a function on a null reference. Also, you seem to misunderstand inheritance -- `super()` will call Object's constructor, not your subclasses. Do your subclasses initialize root in their own constructors?

Comment: No they don't! I just started haha, thanks I put super in all derived already and put it in the base class for some reason -_-

Comment: If you try `root->add_comment` on a `NULL` pointer in C++ you will get a segmentation fault. This is the analogous situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your instance variable `root` is declared but never initialized. So , you are trying to invoke a method `root.add_comments(root, comment);` on `null` reference . it is effectively `null.add_comments(root, comment);` , hence a NullPointerException.

```
protected tree root; // is declared , never initialized.
```

You need to initialize it somehow .

```
protected tree root = new tree();
```

Or pass a new instance of `tree` in the `destination` constructor and assign it to the instance variable.

```
public destination(tree root)
{
    super();        
    this.root = root;
}
```

This is how you do a null-check in Java :

```
if(root!=null) { // lowercase "null"
     root.add_comments(root, comment);
}
```

**P.S. :** Please follow Java's [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

Comment: I'm not trying to initialize it yet, I wanted it to be a null pointer, because then I check if (root == NULL) then I would create the tree node.

Comment: Then you need to check `if (root == null)` (lowercase) before each time you try to use it (and create the instance)

Comment: Ah, ok, but I'm trying to make it so the tree class handles the creation of the tree nodes. Is there a way to have root stay null and be able to call the function from the tree node?

Comment: @SieuPhan You can't call _any_ methods on a `null` reference.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize `root`. Unlike C++, in Java all variables are treated as references / pointers, so no instances are created until a `new` instruction is processed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to initialize `root`, otherwise it is set to `null` as you've seen. You can either initialize it in the constructor (i.e.,)

```
public destination()
{
    super();
    root = new tree();
}
```

or give a default initialization when you declare it.

```
protected tree root = new tree();
```

Think of it as a reference to a tree rather than a tree itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `tree root`

```
tree root  =  new tree();
```